# href and bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement a modal functionality with an application and I am bit stuck.

use case: On an user's dashboard they are bunch of links for the various applications. When user tries to access those link, a modal with terms and condition should pops and when the user accepts the condition then a new windows should open depending on the application link user selected. These links are dynamic and generated on UI based on database.

Non modal implementation:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" nopadding>
    <ul class="nopadding padded-side-20">
        <c:forEach var="app" items="${appAndLink}">
            <li><a href="#" onClick="openJSWindow('${app.value}', '${app.key}', true)">${app.key}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>                                                                
    </ul>
</div>
```

Modal Implementation:

```
<c:forEach var="app" items="${appAndLink}">
    <li><a href="#" id="modalbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-height=320 data-width=450 data-target="#myModalAccessApp">${app.key}</a></li>
</c:forEach>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAccessApp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalAccessAppLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header nopadding padded-side-20 padded-tb-10">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalAccessAppLabel">
                    Systems Use Notification
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 gray-divider"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id ="modalID">
                <p> Terms and condition </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="openJSWindow('${app.value}', '${app.key}', true)" data-dismiss="modal">
                    I Accept
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                </button>
            </div><!-- /.modal-footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /.modal-Ends --> 

</ul>
</div>
```

I am not able to pass the `${app.value}`, `${app.key}` value to the modal which I have created. Kindly let me know if this can be done with jQuery or AJAX. I have very limited knowledge on these.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Use the `data-*` attribute and `relatedTarget` technique: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: thanks phillip100 I just did this https://jsfiddle.net/k7xn88zd/4/embedded/result/